# The map from $SU(2) \times SU(2)$ to $SO(4)$

Tags: lie-groups

Lie group $SO(4)$ is doubly covered by $SU(2) \times SU(2)$, I want to know the map from $SU(2) \times SU(2)$ to $SO(4)$.

The map from $SU_{2}$ to $SO(3)$ is 
$\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\-\overline{\beta} & \overline{ \alpha}  \end{pmatrix}
\longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2}(\alpha^{2}-\beta^{2}+\overline{\alpha}^{2}-\overline{\beta}^{2} & \frac{i}{2}(-\alpha^{2}-\beta^{2}+\overline{\alpha}^{2}+\overline{\beta}^{2} & -\alpha\beta-\overline{\alpha}\overline{\beta}\\\frac{i}{2}(\alpha^{2}-\beta^{2}-\overline{\alpha}^{2}+\overline{\beta}^{2} & \frac{1}{2}(\alpha^{2}+\beta^{2}+\overline{\alpha}^{2}+\overline{\beta}^{2}  & -i(\alpha\beta-\overline{\alpha}\overline{\beta})\\ \alpha\overline{\beta}+\overline{\alpha}\beta & i(-\alpha\overline{\beta}+\overline{\alpha}\beta)&  \alpha\overline{\alpha}-\beta\overline{\beta}    \end{pmatrix}.$
Therefore what is  the image of

$(\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\-\overline{\beta} & \overline{ \alpha}  \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} \alpha' & \beta' \\-\overline{\beta}' & \overline{ \alpha}'  \end{pmatrix})\in SU_{2}\times SU_{2}$

Comment: Do you already know a nice map for the double cover $SU(2)\rightarrow SO(3)$?  The one I know (using quaternions) can be easily tweaked to give the double cover of $SO(4)$.

Comment: Thanks. I know the map $SU(2) \rightarrow SO(3)$, can you explain clearly the map  $SU(2) \times SU(2) \rightarrow SO(4)$?

Comment: The way I think of the map $SU(2)\rightarrow SO(3)$ is by conjugation using quaternions.  Instead of conjugation, use two separate quaternions.  That is, thinking of $SU(2)$ as $Sp(1)$, the double cover is $(p,q)\in Sp(1)^2\mapsto (v\mapsto pvq^{-1})$ where we think of $v\in \mathbb{R}^4\cong \mathbb{H}$.

Comment: Thanks. I re-edit the question. Could you please tell me what is the  image of it?

Comment: The image must be all of $SO(4)$ for general theory reasons ;-).  If I had to do the computation, I would use some sort of Computer Algebra System....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a sketch of the construction; I'll leave the (more or less straightforward) algebraic details to the reader.

Let $\Bbb V$ be the $4$-dimensional (real) vector space of complex $2 \times 2$ matrices $z \in M(2, \Bbb C)$ satisfying $$z^* = J z^{\top}J^{-1}, \qquad J := \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0} .$$

Now, realize $SU(2)$ as the group of matrices $g \in M(2, \Bbb C)$ that satisfy $g^*g = \Bbb I$, and define an action of $SU(2) \times SU(2)$ on $\Bbb V$ by $$(g, h) \cdot z := g z h^* .$$ This action preserves the positive-definite bilinear form $$\langle z, w \rangle := \operatorname{Re}\operatorname{tr}(z w^*)$$ on $\Bbb V$ and so defines a map $SU(2) \times SU(2) \to SO(\Bbb V) \cong SO(4)$; this is the desired double cover.

Computing in a basis for $\Bbb V$---the basis $\left(\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}, \pmatrix{i&0\\0&-i}, \pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}, \pmatrix{0&i\\i&0}\right)$ is both convenient for computation and (up to an overall rescaling) orthonormal with respect to the bilinear form---gives an explicit formula analogous to that for the map $SU(2) \to SO(3)$ in the question statement.

For more details and similar constructions of the other sporadic coverings among Lie groups (both complex and real), see Paul Garrett's useful notes [*Sporadic isogenies to orthogonal groups*](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/%7Egarrett/m/v/sporadic_isogenies.pdf) [pdf].

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome, and I'm glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In physics, this construction is called the [spinor map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group), or the Weyl representation, or the nonlinear (chiral) *σ* model.

Consider the unit determinant 2×2 matrix mapped out of the 3-vector $\vec r \equiv (x,y,z)$,
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{1+\vec r ^2} + z & x - iy \\ x + iy &  \sqrt{1+\vec r ^2}  - z \end{pmatrix}= \sqrt{1+\vec r ^2}~  1\!\!1 +x\sigma_x +y\sigma_y+z\sigma_z ,
$$
and 
your unimodular  ones
$$
L=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\-\overline{\beta} & \overline{ \alpha}  \end{pmatrix},\qquad R=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha' & \beta' \\-\overline{\beta}' & \overline{ \alpha}'  \end{pmatrix},
$$
so $LXR$ is also unimodular. You may painstakingly do the multiplication and compare entries, to specify the 3×3 matrix M sending $\vec r \equiv (x,y,z)$ to the 3-vector specified by $LXR$. Each element of M will be linear in the unprimed (L) and also primed (R) elements.

Normally, in physics, this is done in a smoother, more efficient language involving the Lie algebra, and the simple expression of group elements in terms of Pauli matrices, $\exp(i \vec r \cdot \vec{\sigma}) = 1\!\! 1\cos{r} + i (\vec r \cdot \vec{\sigma}) \sin{r}/r $ , but this procedure should be equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.